# A 3-regular graph with an even number of vertices is planar?

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs

I'm trying to understand *Complexity of the hamiltonian cycle in regular graph problem* [1]:

I don't understand this part:

> Lemma 2.11: HC-3-regular-(n-even) is NP-complete
>
> The result is obvious since the number of edges of a 3-regular graph is (3/2) n.

I don't understand what is the relation of the number of edges and the citation in the article [2]. As far as I understand a HC-3-regular-(n-even) graph can be non-planar (e.g. for n = 4, it's possible to get the K3,3 graph which is not planar), so I dont understand the argument being made.

---

1. [Complexity of the hamiltonian cycle in regular graph problem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397594901856)
2. [The planar hamiltonian circuit problem is NP-Complete](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos423/handouts/the%20planar%20hamiltonian.pdf)

Comment: 1) This part basically says that in any instance of the HC-3-regular problem, $|V|$ must be even, since otherwise $|E|=\frac 32 |V|$ is not an integer. 2) The reference proves that the HC-3-regular problem is NP-hard. They show that it's true even if you assume that the graphs are planar. Hence, it's also hard without this assumption.

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use code blocks (i.e., indentation) for quotations.  Instead, we prefer that you use a quotation block: prefix each line with `> `.  What exactly is your question? We are a question and answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question.  "I dont understand the argument being made." is too vague and open-ended to be a good fit here.  Can you identify some specific aspect you don't understand and ask about that?

Comment: @Dmitry, write that in an answer instead of in a comment, so we can upvote it?

Comment: @Dmitry thanks!! That makes sense.

Comment: @D.W. I improved the format, but not sure how I could have rephrased the question better. The author wrote "The result is obvious" and it wasn't obvious to me (thanks Dmitry for clarifying).

Comment: We require you to ask an explicit question.  "I don't understand..." is not a question.  I can't tell what your question is.  Are you asking: how do I prove the lemma?  Are you asking: what does the lemma mean?  Something else?  If you're trying to understand what the statement of the lemma is saying, please explain your own understanding and what specifically you don't understand about it.  Please formulate a specific question  you want answered, and [edit] your post to ask a question.  Normally, a question ends with a "?", not a "."